# TCP socket in Python getting Hung Up after Several hours of Running continuously

Tags: python, ssl, tcpserver

I have a python script that acts as a server that is getting hung up somewhere. After about 24 hours of running, the server seems to stop listening and responding entirely. I don't understand what is causing it because it behaves perfectly normal all the way up to that point, and I'v been trying to write to a log to see if any exceptions occur before it happens, and so far I haven't been able to find anything. It's my understanding that Python's TCP socket automatically queues client connections.

```
def ssl_server():
    #logger("MAIN", "ssl_server", "SERVER", "")
    #_logger_("MAIN", "ssl_server", "SERVER", "")
    
    global run

    run            = True
    non_ssl_thread = Thread(target = non_ssl_server, args = (server_config["enable-https"]["force-ssl"]["force"],server_config["enable-https"]["force-ssl"]["true-path"]))
    SERVER_HOST    = server_config["server-host"]
    tcp_socket     = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM, 0)
    
    try:
        if not(server_config["enable-https"]["enabled"]):
            raise Exception("HTTPS Disabled")
        
        SERVER_PORT = 443
        context     = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS_SERVER)
        context.load_cert_chain(server_config["cert-location"])
        tcp_socket.bind((SERVER_HOST, SERVER_PORT))
        non_ssl_thread.daemon = True
        non_ssl_thread.start()
        tcp_socket.listen(server_config["queue-limit"])
        ssl_tcp_socket = context.wrap_socket(tcp_socket, server_side=True)
        listener(ssl_tcp_socket)
    except:
        #logger("MAIN", "ssl_server", "SERVER", "EXCEPTION: " + traceback.format_exc().replace('"', '&#34;').replace('<', "&#60;").replace('>', "&#62;").replace('\n', "<br>").replace(' ', "&#160;"))
        
        run = False
        tcp_socket.close()
        non_ssl_server()

    ssl_tcp_socket.close()
    
    try:
        tcp_socket.close()
    except:
        #logger("MAIN", "ssl_server", "SERVER", "EXCEPTION: " + traceback.format_exc().replace('"', '&#34;').replace('<', "&#60;").replace('>', "&#62;").replace('\n', "<br>").replace(' ', "&#160;"))
        pass
#END ssl_server()

def listener(_socket_, redirect_to_ssl = False, true_path = False):
    #logger("MAIN", "listener", "SERVER", "")
    #_logger_("MAIN", "listener", "SERVER", "")
    
    global run
    
    while run:
        try:
            (client_connection, client_address) = _socket_.accept()
            client_request                      = client_connection.recv(server_config["socket-buffer-size"]).decode()
            server_response                     = initialized_handler.respond_to_request(client_request, client_address, redirect_to_ssl, true_path)

            client_connection.sendall(server_response)
            client_connection.close()
        except:
            #logger("MAIN", "listener", "SERVER", "EXCEPTION: " + traceback.format_exc().replace('"', '&#34;').replace('<', "&#60;").replace('>', "&#62;").replace('\n', "<br>").replace(' ', "&#160;"))
            pass
#END listener()
```

I've tried logging exceptions, and logging client requests and server responses, and as far as I can tell, the python script server seems to stop listening and responding even though it is still "running". Interestingly though, the non-SSL TCP socket running in a separate thread doesn't ever get hung up. While the SSL TCP socket running in the main thread is hung up, the non-SSL TCP socket in the separate thread still accepts client requests and responds to them. Since they are both using the same `listener()` function, I can only assume it has something to do with the Python SSL wrapper, but I don't know for certain.

Comment: Sounds like the behavior you are describing can be explained by this code: `run = False`, `tcp_socket.close()`, `non_ssl_server()` you kill your threaded processes by changing the global `run`, close your socket, then start another non_ssl_server which keeps listening.

Comment: I am currently testing that. Something has to be throwing an exception for it to be doing that. I'm not entirely sure what it is yet.

Comment: It is very obvious now that I look at it. I'm not sure how I missed it. I still have a lot more debugging to do though because I am catching exceptions everywhere throughout the code since client requests are a wild animal and you never know what you will get.

So far, none of the exceptions that I have found seem to be related to it, so I'm going to have to do a lot more debugging. What ever is causing the exception has to be something very specific and only seems to happen on occasion, because the server has been running for a while now with no issue and I haven't made any changes.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the behavior you are describing can be explained by this code: `run = False`, `tcp_socket.close()`, `non_ssl_server()` you kill your threaded processes by changing the global run, close your socket, then start another non_ssl_server which keeps listening.
[DragonBobZ Dec 26, 2022 at 22:28]